# Merging PDF files with similar names using PDFTK and a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, pdf, merge, pdftk

I have a directory with a few hundred PDFs in it.

All of the PDFs filenames begin with a 5 digit number (and then have a bunch of other stuff at the end).

What I need to do is merge any PDFs together that start with the same 5 digit number.

Thoughts on how to do this via a shell script? Or other options? I'm using `pdftk` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -type f -iname "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*.pdf" -printf "%.5f\n" \
  | sort -u \
  | while read -r file; do 
         echo pdftk ${file}*.pdf cat output $file.pdf ;
    done
```

If output is okay, remove `echo`.

Comment: This worked perfectly, much appreciated! I'm curious how I could have done this myself (I'm new to linux--mostly just write javascript and autohotkey in windows), if you have a second, do you mind pointing me toward a guide toward this kind of scripting, or even what language you're doing this in?

Comment: As an introduction to the subject take a look at [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Comment: ... with the usual caution that parts of the ABS is not actually a good example of how to do things.  See e.g. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/tutoriallist#advanced_bash_scripting_guide_abs